# How to convert to json to object by passing the object type

Tags: java, json, generics, casting

```
 public static Object convertToObject(String json) {
    validate("json", json);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Object>(){});
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert json to object: "+json, ex);
    }
 }

//Here I'm doing type cast for the returned object
  Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> convertedMap = (Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>>) RestClient.convertToObject(json);
```

I tried above code
I'm using jackson and I need to pass the json with type so that I can avoid the type cast in the caller place.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Object mapper requires 2nd Parameter as a `Class` type, so try passing:

```
Object.class
```

as below:

```
return mapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use this method in common class for Mapper initialization

```
public static ObjectMapper getJacksonMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
    mapper.setVisibility(VisibilityChecker.Std.defaultInstance().withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY));
    return mapper;
}
```

Second thing, you should create POJO class for the corresponding json. Finally you can get the json string has to be converted as POJO class and you can use it very easily.

```
SamplePOJO poListResponse = AppUtils.getJacksonMapper().readValue(jsonString, SamplePOJO.class);
```